# Store foreign key on field other than Id in persistent

Tags: haskell, persistent

I am trying to create a foreign key constraint on a Unique field that I created. Here is the TemplateHaskell for the model:

```
User json
  user_id      Text
  name         Text
  UniqueUserId user_id
  deriving Show Eq

UserPicture
  user_id           Text
  picture           ByteString
  UniqueUserPicture user_id
  -- Foreign           User UserPictureUser_id UserUser_id
  deriving Show Eq
```

How can I make it such that `user_id` in `UserPicture` is a reference to `user_id` in `User`? That way I could probably also cascade deletes of a `User` and maybe even get all pictures to a user more easily.

Update: Alright so it is necessary to define the field as the primary key. Like this in this case:

```
User json 
  user_id      Text 
  name         Text 
  UniqueUserId user_id 
  Primary      user_id 
  deriving Show Eq

UserPicture
   user_id           Text
   picture           ByteString
   UniqueUserPicture user_id
   Foreign           User fkUser user_id
   deriving Show Eq
```

Comment: I think you have to use some *semi*-documented features - look here for [examples using different prim-keys and foreign keys](https://github.com/yesodweb/persistent/blob/master/persistent-test/CompositeTest.hs#L53) (look for `Primary name name2 age`) and here is a nice [overview over some other mappings](https://www.schoolofhaskell.com/school/advanced-haskell/persistent-in-detail/existing-database)

Comment: Yes, I have seen that _documentation_ but I don't really get it. That's where I have that comment on the penultimate line from. But that is giving me a headache.

Comment: Update: I get it now, I have to specify the primary key first. Okay, I would have liked it to be possible without that.

Comment: Well how should it know? And of course it needs to be the prim.key (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_key)) that's how the stuff works usually

Comment: btw: I guess the you don't need `UniqueUserId` once you made it the `Primary` ;)

Comment: Can you include that as a separate answer ?

Comment: Who do you mean, Sibi?